# Rename Windows-10 tag to 10-mobile?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Currently the [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) tag is used for questions regarding the Windows 10 Mobile insider preview. This usage is not consitent with other version tags, as [8.1](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8.1) and [wp8.1](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp8.1) are used for Windows Phone, [windows-8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) is used for the desktop OS.

Considering that there is a difference between Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile I suggest renaming [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) to either [windows-10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-mobile) or just [10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10-mobile).

I also created a specific [insider-preview](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insider-preview) tag since this program will continue for the desktop OS after the official release and I expect it to do so for mobile as well. EDIT: I just realized there is [technical-preview](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-preview). Should this be renamed as well as [Microsoft is officially calling it insider preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-download-phone)?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think I created that tech preview. Will change the name. And I agree with `windows-10-mobile` just let's wait more feedback.

Comment: [Trying to get mods support to rename site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308700/rename-windowsphone-se-to-windowsmobile-se)

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, the answer is yes.

The [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) tag is not consistent with other version tags and it could raise some confusion with the desktop version of Windows 10.

I think too [windows-10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-mobile) or [10-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10-mobile) will be better tags instead of the current one.

Comment: I don't know how to insert the tag symbols in my answer like you did. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags

Comment: @Thomas thank you, I modified my answer.

Comment: Agreed, especially since the documentation on it specifically says it's for PCs. IMO it should be named `windows-10-mobile`.

Comment: I prefer [tag:windows-10-mobile]. It sounds clear.

Comment: @Shawn Not agreeing here, a description for a tag should be changed, not adding an extra tag if it's not correctly formulated. SO maybe [tag:windows-10-mobile] could be still relevant, I still think it's a start of to much diversity. Just add more tags to be more precise...

Comment: @Depechie Could you please clarify what you mean? I was saying that we should create a new windows-10-mobile tag. You said, "...a description for a tag should be changed, not adding an extra tag..." and then you said, "...Just add more tags to be more precise...", which seems entirely contradictory. I'm sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: @Shawn I mean that the addition of mobile to an os has no meaning so using separate tags is my favourite

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it's me, but aren't questions supposed to be able to use multiple tags to specify what's it about?

So I would prefer [windows-10](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) and [mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile) or [phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone) as 2 separate tags to a given question.

Why do I suggest this, because in reference to Windows 10 ( the OS ) it will more and more become less relevant to know the differences between several devices. A question that is a current problem only on Phone could become a problem on for example iot once features are enabled ( in theory ).
Seeing the nature of the OS, it's all about 1 overall.

Maybe a case can be made for the current suggest tag, but I' fearing tags as [windows-10-mobile-8inch-butnotphone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-mobile-8inch-butnotphone) if you understand my point :)
( in other words an 8inch device with sim card but isn't a phone )

Comment: Here [tag:10-mobile] or [tag:windows-10-mobile] will point to the devices using mobile version of the operating system and not the the handsets. So a 8inch device without a sim card may use the [tag:windows-10-mobile] tag if it runs Windows10-mobile.